# Oracle: Selecting Duplicates with where clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question: Why can't I just use the following SQL query to get a list of unique eMail addresses from the `PERSON` table?

```
SELECT NOT DISTINCT Email FROM PERSON
```

Comment: NOT DISTINCT is definitely not Oracle syntax.

Comment: Not really an answer, so I'll just leave this as a comment. The `NOT` operator applies to `boolean`s, which "DISTINCT email" is not. What you want would be expressed (mathematically) as `SELECT email FROM person EXCEPT SELECT DISTINCT email FROM person`. They are (usually) more efficient to write this query though (I'll leave that to actual answers).

Comment: Questions as to why the SQL standard does or does not do something should be directed to the standards committee:  https://www.iso.org/committee/45342.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest and common way to achieve this is with grouping by the Email column and then keep the records having count = 1.

```
SELECT Email, COUNT(Email)
FROM PERSON
GROUP BY Email
HAVING COUNT(Email) > 1;
```

NOT DISTINCT is not working because it is not a valid expression.
DISTINCT is used to return only different values, so NOT before it is not working as you expect.

Comment: The question was how to get unique emails, not how to get those with multiple instances. Actually, the question was 'Why can't I...' which is a very bad question. The answer to that is *because it doesn't work.'

Answer (score 0):

You asked *to get a list of unique eMail addresses*, which is done by:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Email) FROM PERSON;
```

Standard SQL does not have `NOT DISTINCT` or anything like that.

Comment: I want the duplicates to be printed not the unique ones, thanks for contributing, I did not know that NOT cannot be used that way.